# update Provisioning Profile for push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning

I have a wildcard provisioning profile for several apps.

We want to add push notifications to the app, and I have read that than each app must have its own provisioning profile and push certificate.

Is this going to affect the existing app installation on user devices? In other words, after updating and publishing the app will it still be a update for the user or is it going to be a new installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you used a wildcard, you'll be able to see in the iOS Provisioning Portal that your app is not capable of being configured to use Push Notifications.  You'll have to create a new ID and profile.

If you make a new provisioning profile and App ID, you have to use the same bundle identifier name (BIN) of your existing app in order to be able to provide updates.  Since your current BIN has a wildcard, you won't be able to create the same one. Thus, your users won't notice the update for the new app.

My recommendation is that you create a new app, capable of handling push notifications, and ask your current users to download that one on an update.  Apple allows you to create an update of an existing app telling them to download the new version.